# MacOS: check for "Full disk access" privacy option

Tags: macos

How can I check with my C application whether it has "Full disk access" permission in the System Preferences > Security & Privacy > Privacy?

There is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57974020/) but the answer uses an outdated link and actually does not answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now 2021, and there is still no API that prompts the user to enable Full Disk Access or queries on is it enabled.

There are some [hacks](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/114452) with reading some files, which on some system versions would be accessible only if the app has FDA enabled.

There is also some useful [info](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/362865/macos-list-apps-authorized-for-full-disk-access) if you could disable SIP.

Nothing more.